# How to get the index of the selected node in a selcted level in a JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am using a JTree in which new nodes needs to be inserted dynamically to the root(consider adding children to root). Once the user selects a node and clicks a button, the new node needs to be added after the selected node. If none of the node is selected then it adds the new node at the end of the tree. Below is my code

```
        public void addNodeToRoot(TestCase testCase) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(testCase.toString());
        int currentNoOfChildren = getTcBuilderTree().getModel().getChildCount(getTcBuilderTree().getModel().getRoot());
        TreePath currentSelection = getTcBuilderTree().getSelectionPath();
        int currentIndex=0;
        //if the user has not selected a node add the test case at the end of the tree
        if (currentSelection == null) {
            currentIndex = currentNoOfChildren;
        }
        //if user has selected a node then insert the new node after the selected node
        else {
                int[] currentSelectedIndex = getTcBuilderTree().getSelectionRows();
                currentIndex = currentSelectedIndex[0];

        }
        treeModel.insertNodeInto(childNode, getRoot(), currentIndex);
    }
```

it works all fine but the code gives an exception when there are child nodes in the level 3 as well. The reason is when the tree has more levels and when its expanded then the currentIndex gives unexpected number (it counts all the indexes in all levels up from the root to the selected node) and the app gives **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** since the **currentIndex** becomes greater than **currentNoOfChildren**

If the tree is not expanded then everything happens correctly. Please let me know how to resolve this. Is there any other way to get the no of children of a specific level in the tree?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe code below can resolve your problem.

```
int currentNoOfChildren = getTcBuilderTree().getVisibleRowCount();
```

Comment: This doesn't work out. It throw the same exception. The issue is existing with the current selected index not with the no of children

Comment: Which case causing the exception? (a node selected or not). Another question: if a node selected in level 3, do you want to add the new node to that level or to root level? If you want to add it to level 3 you must change the parent node as well.

Comment: 'When the second level nodes have child nodes and when the last second level node is selected' is where the exception throws. i am using two integers to get the current selected node's index and the no of children of the root node. the current selected index changes when the tree is collapsed with some or all of its sub levels.  answering to your second question. when i select a thrid level node and add a new node, nothing should happen (this is working) when the root or a second level node is selected then the  new node adds to root. I will try to add an image above

Comment: I couldn't try it now but `DefaultMutableTreeNode` has a method named `getIndex`. Maybe you can call it from your root node and give the selected node as a parameter returns a correct index for you. you can get the node object by call `getLastPathComponent` method from `TreePath`.